# Should I show a separate version of my Ajax-driven GWT site to search bots?

Tags: ajax, gwt, seo

I'm building a website (using [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)), so it's **very** heavy on AJAX.

Due to this, should I create a separate 'view' of my website for search engines?

For instance, one thought is to write a separate servlet that detects if the viewer is a search bot, and if so, return an unformatted page (no CSS) with all the data contained by the full version of the site.  Is this a good idea?

Is there something else I should be considering?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I think the term for this might be 'cloaking' which I've heard is bad... any insight?

Comment: No do not show a different page to search engines, while showing a page without CSS isn't to bad they may consider it a gateway page or doorway page. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorway_page for more information.

Comment: What would be the benefits of that? The cost would be more work (write code to strip down CSS).

Comment: @milan - the benefit would be that the search crawlers see our content, as opposed to nothing.  When I crawl the site now using the Google User Agent in Firefox, the site's effectively blank.  I'm trying to figure out exactly what we should do, since our current state is very bad from a search engine perspective.

Comment: @Anagio - do you have any idea what to do instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GWT but whatever you do don't show the bots a different version of your site. Rather than spoofing your user agent. You should login to Google webmaster tools then have Google Bot crawl your site and view any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google suggests ways to make your AJAX application (GWT or not) Google-crawlable in their [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html) guide.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the crawling, since we can easily generate a sitemap.xml.  More concerned with getting HTML content to Google, since without Javascript, our GWT site is basically empty.

Comment: @Cuga well that's what Google means by "crawling" - the ability of Google bots to extract and index the content of your site despite being unable to run JS. They propose a special URL syntax and a server side contract (basically, your server is supposed to deliver an HTML snapshot of your AJAX app's content when a special URL query parameter is present in the request URL).